# If mapping is a homomorphism, then cardinality of ring is uniquely determined

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $(R,+,\cdot)$ be a ring with identity where $0\neq 1$ and $|R|>2$. Define $\varphi :R\to R$ with $\varphi (x) := x^{10}$.

> Show that if $\varphi$ is a group endomorphism (of $(R,+)$), then $R$ consists of precisely four elements.

**Ignore this topic**

Comment: This is not true.  Are you sure you haven't left out any hypotheses?

Comment: @EricWofsey oh, have you thought of a counter-example? No, this is the problem. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false.  For instance, if $R$ is a product of any number of copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2$, then $x^2=x$ for all $x\in R$ and so $\varphi$ is the identity map, which is a group endomorphism.

Comment: Oh dear, thanks for putting my mind at ease!